# How do I maintain a Bluetooth connectivity when switching activities?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I can't for the life of me figure out how to use a service to keep my Bluetooth connection active when switching activities. I'm trying to send some commands to a OBD2 adapter. So I can't do this because the Bluetooth connection dies. I have a `Handler` in `MainActivity` that handles the gui of `BTHandler`. I don't know if that will interfere with the `Service` if created?

ANY help is appreciated!

Thanks

**BTHandler**

```
public class BTHandler {

    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

    final ArrayList<String> devices = new ArrayList();
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private BluetoothDevice device;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private BluetoothSocket socket;
    private String status;
    private int mState;
    private boolean connectionStatus = false;

    public BTHandler(Context context, Handler handler) { // Konstruktor
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    public void write(String s) {
        mConnectedThread.sendRawCommand(s);
        Log.v("write", "write");
    }

    /*
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    */
    public void connect(String deviceAddress) {
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(deviceAddress);
        mConnectThread.start();
    }

    private void guiHandler(int what, int arg1, String obj) {
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.what = what;
        msg.obj = obj;
        msg.arg1 = arg1;
        msg.sendToTarget();
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

        public ConnectThread(String deviceAddress) {
            mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            device = mAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);

            BluetoothAdapter mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            BluetoothDevice device = mAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
            UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
            try {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                //socket.connect();
                //Log.v("connect", "connect");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                //Log.v("exception", "e");
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes;

            try {
                // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
                Log.v("connect", "connect");
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                    Log.v("close", "close");
                } catch (IOException closeException) {
                }
                guiHandler(Constants.TOAST, Constants.SHORT, "Connection Failed");
                return;
            }
            guiHandler(Constants.CONNECTION_STATUS, Constants.STATE_CONNECTED, "");
            mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
            mConnectedThread.start();
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
        private ObdMultiCommand multiCommand;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            connectionStatus = true;
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;

            try {
                //RPMCommand engineRpmCommand = new RPMCommand();
                //SpeedCommand speedCommand = new SpeedCommand();
                ModuleVoltageCommand voltageCommand = new ModuleVoltageCommand();

                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    //engineRpmCommand.run(mmInStream, mmOutStream); //(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
                    //speedCommand.run(mmInStream, mmOutStream); //(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
                    voltageCommand.run(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
                    // TODO handle commands result
                    //Log.d("Log", "RPM: " + engineRpmCommand.getFormattedResult());
                    //Log.d("Log", "Speed: " + speedCommand.getFormattedResult());
                    Log.v("Log", "Voltage: " + voltageCommand.getFormattedResult());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            OBDcmds();
            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (connectionStatus) {
                sendMultiCommand();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        // CALL this to MainActivity
        public void sendRawCommand(String command) {
            try {
                new OdbRawCommand(command);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("sendRawCommand", "e");
            }
        }

        private void OBDcmds() { // execute commands

            try {
                new EchoOffCommand().run(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
                new LineFeedOffCommand().run(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
                new TimeoutCommand(100).run(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
                new SelectProtocolCommand(ObdProtocols.AUTO).run(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream()); //ISO_15765_4_CAN

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("OBDcmds", "e");
                // handle errors
            }
        }
        /*
        // Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        */

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        public void sendMultiCommand() {
            try {
                // RUN some code here
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SPA**

```
public class SPA extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button b2;
    BTHandler btHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sp);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getValue);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        String voltage = ("AT RV");

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.getValue:
                btHandler.write(voltage);
                Log.v("Log", "getValue" + voltage);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**MyService**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The new Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // For time consuming an long tasks you can launch a new thread here...
        // Do your Bluetooth Work Here
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

**Handler in MainActivity**

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case BTHandler.STATE_CONNECTED:
                            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_connected);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Connected.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.title_connected_to, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.v("Log", "Connected");
                            break;
                        case BTHandler.STATE_NONE:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.title_not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Why not put all your BT related gubbins in the Service? Such as your `BTHandler`.

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm trying to do but i do not know how I would do it? Can I just put the whole BTHandler class under onStartCommand in MyService?

Comment: use a service, otherwise your connection will get lost every time you change to a new activity

Comment: @Xoce웃Пepeúpa Hi, yes I know. Would you mind showing how I can approach this?

Comment: @Knossos Could you help me with this?

Comment: That is quite a broad question. You would be better off learning from a Service tutorial. Once you have done that, you should know how you can put your BTHandler in the Service and communicate between your Service and your Activity.

Comment: @Knossos I have looked up some tutorials on Android services and I kind of under stand the gist of it. But I don't know how I can make my `BTHandler` class into a service; I need some type of guidance. Basically I don't know where things should go when moving my code in my `BTHandler` class into my `MyService` class